# Listening to the Qur'an and studying- permissible or disrespectful?

Tags: sunni

I am new to the practice of Islam and i have a lot of questions but among them is the fallowing: I spend a lot of time reading for my school and though I try to make time for reading the QUR'AN it isn't enough. So, I was wondering, is it ok to play the Qur'an while I am studying? Will I benefit from it? or is it disrespectful and I should not do so?

Looking forward to getting a response.

May Allah reward you !

Comment: 'playing it in the background' which your priority is elsewhere is IMO very disrespectful and Allah will not look well on you.

Comment: I never heard something like "you can't listen Quran at this conditions". Respect and disrespect are all about taqwa. If you feel uncomfortable, don't do it. In my opinion, listening Quran ,instead of listening something else, is better approach. And it gives an opportunity to learn Quran quickly, because I feel like I am more familiar with Quran and I feel like Quran with me all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According this [explanation](http://www.islam-qa.com/en/14590) it is preferred to focus on Quran recitation. So, it is not recommended parallel activities. 
In your case, you are studying and listening. It will be hard for you to concentrate on both at the same time. Though studying is not a disrespectful activity, there are activities that could disrespect Quran while doing in parallel.
See, like if you are travelling and you are not the driver, you can listen to Quran. In this case you are not disrespecting Al-Quran :)